# Complete negation or partial? "I don't think anybody X"

Tags: negation, some-any

> "I don't think anybody saw it coming."

I assume that this sentence means that the speaker thinks nobody saw it coming, but can't this pattern "I don't think anybody X" be took as "I think that not everybody X (but I think some X,)" in some context?

In other words, do you always take the example sentence I quoted from [this article](http://www.indystar.com/story/sports/college/notre-dame/2016/11/09/irishs-mike-mcglinchey-election-dont-think-anybody-saw-coming/93554704/) as "I think nobody saw it coming," not as "I think not everybody saw it coming, but I believe some did at least?"

Comment: Please [clarify your specific problem](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could wrangle a partial negation from it by arguing that it is hyperbole or that the speaker lacks complete information, but on a straightforward reading, it's a complete negation.

Comment: To answer the final question, Yes: " not ... anybody" is always the same as "nobody"; it is never "somebody".

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not the way it works.

First, *anybody* here is a [Negative Polarity Item](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A15299%20%22negative%20polarity%20item%22), triggered by the negative in *don't think*. So it's just part of the machinery, a constant `X` set to zero. Putting it there as the subject of the complement clause links the clause to the negative in the higher clause, which leads to the next point.

Let's dispose of the *any* and just substitute a noun to illustrate the structures, OK?

Second, *think* is what's called a [Negative-Raising](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20negative%20raising) verb, like *believe* (but unlike *know* or *claim*).  Neg-Raising is the phenomenon that relates (for instance)

- *Bill thinks that Mike is not coming.*

and

- *Bill does not think that Mike is coming*.

The negation of *think* in the first is intended and interpreted as a negation of *be coming*, as in the second. So the two sentences are synonymous. Neg-Raising is governed by *think*, and *believe*, but not by *know* or *claim*, since the second examples are **not** synonymous:

- *Bill doesn't think/believe Mike is coming.* = *Bill thinks/believes Mike isn't coming.*

**but**

- *Bill doesn't know/claim Mike is coming.* **≠**  *Bill knows/claims Mike isn't coming.*

This is the more normal situation; Neg-Raising is a minor rule, governed by only a few mental predicates. We say that these predicates are "transparent to negation", since a reading of outside negation with *think* or *believe* (like there is with *know* and *claim*) is very hard to produce, and generally requires very careful stress, intonation, and rhythm to accomplish successfully.